# Delete files do not exist in source folder in cmd?

Tags: cmd, backup, xcopy

I have two folders that I backup from source to destination folder using command:

```
xcopy /E /Y /I /D
```

Now I want to delete files in destination folder that do not exist in source folder.

Answer (score 13):

There is no 'mirroring' option in xcopy. I have 2 suggestions:
1. 
you could run `xcopy dest source /L > todelete.txt` to obtain a list of files which exist in dest but not in source. Then use a `for` loop to delete these files in `dest`.

or

2.
Use `robocopy` which was designed to use the same options as `xcopy` but has a lot more funtionality. For instance, a `/MIR` option to mirror one folder to the other. `robocopy` is included in all Windows versions from Vista on (the Win7 version might run under XP as well - not tested though).
Besides, it is way faster and and and...